# Code rending different - page numbers showing in header against edge

Tags: classicthesis

[image: A]

This is the code rendered from ShareLateX - and the same code rendered locally withTeXMaker and TeXSTudio

[image: B]

Any idea whow to get rid of that floating page number?

```
   % cv example for classicthesis.sty
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[LabelsAligned]{currvita} % nice cv style
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[nochapters]{classicthesis}
% Some font experiments
%\usepackage[osf]{libertine}
%\usepackage{hfoldsty}
%\usepackage[math]{iwona} %[light,condensed,math]
%\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{iwona}
%\usepackage{lmodern} % <-- no osf support :-(
%\usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign} %<-- no osf support :-(

\renewcommand*{\cvheadingfont}{\LARGE\color{Maroon}}
\renewcommand*{\cvlistheadingfont}{\large}
\renewcommand*{\cvlabelfont}{\qquad}

\begin{document}
    \begin{cv}{\spacedallcaps{Curriculum Vit\ae}}
        %\pdfbookmark[1]{Pers\"onliche Daten}{PersDat}
        \begin{cvlist}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Pers\"onliche Daten}}\label{PersDat}  
            \item   Dr.-Ing.~Andr\'e Miede
            \item   Geboren am \dots\ \texttt{(-;} \\   
                    Europ\"aer, Deutsche Staatsb\"urgerschaft 
            \item   \url{http://www.miede.de} \\                
                    \url{https://www.xing.com/profile/Andre_Miede}              
        \end{cvlist}

        %\pdfbookmark[1]{Irgendwas}{irgendwas}
        \begin{cvlist}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{Irgendwas}}\label{irgendwas}
            \item   \dots 
        \end{cvlist}
    \end{cv}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose this has to do with recent upgrades to KOMA-Script. Usually ShareLaTeX lags behind in updates to TeX Live.

A workaround is to add

```
\pagestyle{empty}
```

to the preamble.